# Calculate coefficient of variation by more than one group

Tags: stata

The command `tabstat` can generate coefficient of variation estimates by a single group.

How could I calculate the coefficient of variation for two groups?

As if the following was allowed in Stata:

```
tabstat price, statistics(n mean cv) by(group_var1 group_var2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate and display it manually:

```
bysort group_var1 group_var2 : egen sd = sd(price)
bysort group_var1 group_var2 : egen mean = mean(price)
generate cv = sd / mean

tabdisp group_var1 group_var2, c(cv)
```

You can optionally scale by 100, if you like.